# How git cannot function its .gitignore feature to keep remotely committed file untouched

Tags: github

The **.gitignore** is not working to keep changes in a remotely committed file intact.

I edited *README.md* file remotely through browser GUI, and when I do `git push -f`, the *README.md* is overwritten although:

- .gitignore content is

  > README.md
  > Readme.md

What I have done:

1. `git rm -r --cached .`
2. `git add .`
3. `git rm --cached README.md`

and finally when I do:
`git push -f`
, I end up loosing the changes made in the remote file *README.md*

Comment: It seems you want this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366713/2072269

Comment: .gitignore will prevent you to add a file under version control, not to modify a file already under version control. See the first line of the description in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)